# Can two people share two Dropbox accounts on a single Windows user account?

Tags: windows-7, dropbox

my partner and i share a computer (windows 7) and have just one user profile, so we don't have to log in and out all the time, can we both install dropbox and have two different dropbox folders for two different dropbox accounts on the same user profile?

Comment: The fact that it's two people is -- except maybe regarding ToS conformity -- irrelevant to this question. It would be more useful generally if you rephrased your title e.g. "two Dropbox accounts for the same Windows user account".

Answer (score 4):

From the [Dropbox Forums](http://forums.dropbox.com/topic.php?id=28067), by a Dropbox support person:

> Note that in the vast majority of cases where people are asking about multiple accounts is best solved by Shared Folders. Unless there are two different people using the same computer, which different OS accounts is the proper way of handling it.
>   Third party applications and hacks that are designed to get multiple Dropbox instances running at the same time for one user is not recommended, not only because they are completely unsupported (by the Dropbox team at least), but also because Dropbox is not meant to be utilized in such a manner. So the chance of issues is a lot higher than running Dropbox as per normal.

---

The answers to [this](https://superuser.com/questions/101927/dropbox-can-you-have-multiple-accounts-on-once-computer) question might also help you. Dropbox supports multiple accounts for multiple user accounts on the same machine, but one of the answers enables you to do this without requiring multiple users. It might be against the Terms of Service.

Comment: I couldn't find anything in the Dropbox terms that would disallow that sort of use.

Comment: @Ilari I'd have quoted if I'd found something (I also looked), but several people in the first thread linked in my post seem to think so. Therefore "might be".

Comment: Yeah i imagine they might try to disable it since it would be a way to get extra space without paying for it by starting multiple accounts, hence i haven't tried it yet, just in our case there are two of us with one home computer and different work computers to sync to. And it's too annoying to set up multiple user accounts for when one of us wants to jump on for just a few minutes.

Comment: @Bec As I wrote, it's conceivable it's forbidden, but I read the ToS and didn't find anything -- so I linked to possible technical solutions at the end of my post. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

You could always use two instances of [Dropbox Portable](http://wiki.dropbox.com/DropboxAddons/DropboxPortable) each with their own directory. I'm not sure whether you would need to quit one before using the other - you'd have to try it.

Comment: Discontinued and no download link according to the web page.